# SetVisibility doesn't work?

Tags: android, layout, visibility

I'm new to developing with android. I have a grid contained in a `LinearLayout` and each item which makes up the grid is a button. I want this `LinearLayout` to be invisible when the user pushes any of these buttons.

This is my 'home' layout shell:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <TextView/>
  <LinearLayout>   //<-- this is the layout I want to hide
     <TextView/>
     <GridView/>
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the onClick method which I've set up in MyArrayAdapter (used to inflate buttons)

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   View convertView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_home, null);  
   LinearLayout ll_options = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ll_options);
   ll_options.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

I think it should work but when I test it, nothing happens.

I found a similar question but it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why are you inflating a layout here?:

```
View convertView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_home, null);
```

Just do:

```
View v = activity.findViewById(R.id.ll_options);
v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: All rigth, that was the mistake. Thank you for fast anwers!

Answer (score 2):

You create a new view which is not in the visible view hierarchy until you add it there, and then you hide that. So you hide something invisible.

Instead, try:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   findViewById(R.id.ll_options).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

which should IMO work. It searches for the `ll_options` view inside the visible (global) view hierarchy of your activity and hides that.

Comment: This is right, though you may actually prefer `View.GONE` to `View.INVISIBLE`, depending on the application.

Comment: yup, depending on whether you want to free up the space the view took (GONE) or just hide it but keep it's space (INVISIBLE), just setting it invisible is also faster if you change between visible and invisible a lot since the view hierarchy is not changed

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Where is your button? Is it in the same layout-file?
You inflate a **new layout** and hide the LinearLayout there, but this new layout is never used. Be sure you have access to the contentView in your listener.